# Join not working for group_concat set MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Essentially, I'm trying to match multiple words with same id, not having luck, the following works:

```
SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(word order by word) as theset, count(*) FROM words 
GROUP BY id HAVING theset like '%foo%bar%' or '%bar%foo%';
```

But I need a join on another table for the rest of the data I need to return, the following doesn't work:

```
SELECT words.id, table.id, table.description, words.occurence , 
GROUP_CONCAT(word order by word) as theset, count(*) 
 FROM words JOIN table 
      on  table.id=words.id 
 GROUP BY words.id HAVING theset LIKE '%foo%bar%' or '%bar%foo%';
```

I'm not sure what's missing.  I have scoured the net looking for a solution, I know there's a lot of resources available for SQL but I can't put my finger on what the issue is - sorry if there is an identical question (I didn't see one)

Comment: can you explain *the following doesn't work* ?  or atleast post the error  details you got after running this query

Comment: Having is intended for group conditions not for row filter.

Comment: Sorry, for example, the first example returns a single row (that I've verified by hand is the correct ID) but when I attempt to JOIN the two tables (table has corresponding ID to many word values) it no longer returns the same row.  Basically I just want the same row, with all the columns I'm specifying.  There are no syntax errors.

Comment: To clarify further, I mean the second example returns nothing.

Comment: do you have the ids returned by first query in the table "table" ?

Comment: Yes, I just re-verified for sanity's sake.

Comment: @danihp hmm, so if that's the case, and I can't just use WHERE due to unexpected WHERE syntax error, then what recommendation would you have for me?